# What is the life cycle of celery's parent tasks?

Tags: python, celery

What is the life cycle of a parent task?

```
group(add.s(i, i) for i in xrange(100))()
```

If I call this group function within a parent task, will the parent wait until all the sub tasks end before ending itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a parent task and called group from it. I just added a delay in `add` so that it will take a while to execute it.

```
@app.task()
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(10)
    return x + y


@app.task()
def parent():
    print('start')
    group(add.s(i, i) for i in xrange(100))()
    print('stop')
```

I called parent task.

```
In [3]: r = parent.delay()  

In [4]: r.state
Out[4]: 'SUCCESS'
```

It just scheduled group task and then continued for next step. It **didn't wait** for the subtasks to complete.

However if you want one task to wait for another task, you [can use chain](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains).